# How does one remove an SDL_Event from the event queue?

Tags: sdl-2

I've been looking through the documentation on `SDL_Event`s. Is there a way to remove an `SDL_UserEvent` from the event queue *before* it gets polled by `SDL_PollEvent`? I've tried googling "`sdl remove event`", but came up with bubkis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine events that are on the queue before taking them out of the queue... and then decide to take them out.

Both can be done with SDL_PeepEvents ( http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PeepEvents ).  You can look at  the next N events by passing in SDL_PEEKEVENT as the parameter action; or take them out with SDL_GETEVENT.

It should be possible also to take them with SDL_GETEVENT; edit the events array you get to remove the event you wanted discarded; then call it again with SDL_ADDEVENT to put them back.

At this point, though, I'd have to wonder if you're really getting done what you wanted.  Why not just poll events, and ignore events of the type you wanted discarded?  That's the way I do it.

Comment: There is a case where I need to remove SDL_KEYMAPCHANGED, to prevent users' OS from switching input methods (English -> Japanese, etc.) That's one way I know of that needs to get that event out, or have the program consume the event before the OS gets the chance to consume it. Right now, I don't know how to "consume" it.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [`SDL_FlushEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FlushEvent) or [`SDL_FlushEvents`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FlushEvents).
`SDL_FlushEvent` can be used to remove one specific type of event from the queue, while `SDL_FlushEvents` can be used with values `SDL_USEREVENT` and `SDL_LASTEVENT` in order to remove every user events from the queue.

You might want to use [`SDL_PumpEvents`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents) before, just to update the event queue.

You can also take a look at [`SDL_PeepEvents`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PeepEvents) (with the same `minType` and `maxType` as `SDL_FlushEvents`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an easy way to remove just ONE event of that type, but you can do:

```
SDL_FlushEvents(SDL_USEREVENT, SDL_LASTEVENT);
```

To remove all pending user events already on the queue.

Comment: I do not think this will work, since you do not generally have `SDL_USEREVENT`'s in your queue when you register events, but rather events of type between `SDL_USEREVENT` and `SDL_LASTEVENT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Game::handleEvent() {
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_PumpEvents();
    SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_JOYHATMOTION);     
    SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_JOYAXISMOTION);
    SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_CONTROLLERAXISMOTION);
    SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_MOUSEMOTION);
    SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN);
    SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP);
    SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_FINGERDOWN);
    SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_FINGERUP);
    SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_FINGERMOTION);
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) 
      scene->handleEvent(screen, event)
}
```